# Issues playing audio/sound when pressing button in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, audio

Pretty new to android world, I am having an issue playing audio when clicking a button. The interesting/weird aspect of it is that same code works on my mainactivity but not on secondactivity that I have set up. I am using the same exact code that works on mainactivity. I used that code on mainactivity just to test it, keep in mind no media player has been declared or defined in mainactivity. I did that just to test to see if code works.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15sp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press button to play audio"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AudioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="play"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"




        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is JAVA:

```
package nameiscleared;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AudioButton);




    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audioname);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            mp.start();
        }
    });
 }
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any error when you click on the start button?

Comment: @Naz141 No errors are given when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked nothing happens no audio gets played.

Answer (score 0):

It just my assumption, I think you are not releasing the MediaPlayer when you use it in MainActivity. That is why it is not working on secondActivity. Another mistake is, `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audioname);` need to be in onClick, not in `View.OnClickListener()` bracket. You need to keep in mind that after you used MediaPlayer, you need to release it when it is no longer being used.

> A MediaPlayer can consume valuable system resources. Therefore, you should always take extra precautions to make sure you are not hanging on to a MediaPlayer instance longer than necessary. When you are done with it, you should always call release() to make sure any system resources allocated to it are properly released. For example, if you are using a MediaPlayer and your activity receives a call to onStop(), you must release the MediaPlayer, because it makes little sense to hold on to it while your activity is not interacting with the user (unless you are playing media in the background, which is discussed in the next section). When your activity is resumed or restarted, of course, you need to create a new MediaPlayer and prepare it again before resuming playback - [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

The correct implementation supposed to be like this;

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button playBtn, startActivityBtn;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    playBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    startActivityBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startActivity);
    startActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(null != mediaPlayer){

        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button playBtn;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_econd);

    playBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(null != mediaPlayer){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
}
```

I am not including the layout because both of the layout are very simple. MainActivity has two button, to play and to start another activity. SecondActivity has only play button.

Comment: @Ahmad Yus, I have tried creating it under onClick and same thing happens on there as well. Mainactivity does not have a mediaplayer on there because I don't need one in that activity. Now would i need to initiate MediaPlayer on mainactivity even if I do not need it on there? I only need it on secondactivity.

Comment: Oh! I thought you have MediaPlayer instance in MainActivity. In that case, you can forget MainActivity and try with secondActivity as above.

Comment: I tried the code above but still no audio is played when the button is clicked. No errors are given at any time. It's weird because when I use same code on mainactivity just for testing it works, but not on second activity.